# how to configure CORS in systemD service?

Tags: ubuntu, cors, systemd

setting CORS in systemD service doesn't work.

I have a node module with CORS enabled, is there any way to move the CORS configuration from the code to systemd service?

current setup in the code:

```
private allowCrossDomain(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: () => void) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, Content-Type');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        next();
    }
```

would like to add CORS in myService.service, but below setup doesn't work:

```
[unit]
Description=Tool operation BE
After=network.target
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Environment=BACKEND_HOST=backend-ops-model.com
Environment=BACKEN_MODEL_PORT=80
Environment=res.header='Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://example.com'
WorkingDirectory=/opt/backend-service/operation
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node --experimental-worker /opt/backend-service/operation/node_modules/@gst/operation-service/www.js
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because questions about the Linux operating system and its utilities should, instead, be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The question has been asked and answered [at U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/538894/117549)

Answer (score 0):

this is how fixed the issue. add CORS options as environment variable in the code:

```
  private allowCrossDomain(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: () => void) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', process.env.CORS_ORIGIN_HOST || 'http://localhost:4200');
        ...
```

then add the Environment directive in systemd configuration:

```
[unit]
Description=Tool operation BE
After=network.target
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Environment=BACKEND_HOST=backend-ops-model.com
Environment=BACKEN_MODEL_PORT=80
Environment=CORS_ORIGIN_HOST=http://alterntive.com
WorkingDirectory=/opt/backend-service/operation
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node --experimental-worker /opt/backend-service/operation/node_modules/@gst/operation-service/www.js
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

with configuration above if you don't provide environment variable in systemd the localhost:4200 will be picked as default.
hope it helps others with the same issue.